# How to add/create label stroke?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, label, stroke

I'm trying to add a stroked label to my Xamarin Forms application, at first I thought it would be simple but after hours of googling I couldn't find anything at all.

All I want is the same simple label control with outline/stroke color and thickness properties, something like this:

```xml
<Label Text="Label" TextColor="#0B1751" StrokeColor="#0FBEFE" StrokeThickness="3"/>
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use SkiaSharp or a custom renderer

Comment: The last example is with text: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/text

Comment: Well, I've checked that out, but SkiaSharp is very compex and overkill for such a task. A custom renderer is preferred indeed but I would like if someone can make it for me as I'm not such skilled in Xamarin yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the result like following screenshot?

[image]

If so, you can create a custom renderer to achieve it.

In Android, you can create two `Textview`, make the smaller textview is above the bigger textview. Here is code.
In the IOS, you can achieve it by same way.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(MyLabelRenderer))]
namespace LabelUpdateDemo.Droid
{
   public class MyLabelRenderer: LabelRenderer
    {
        Context context;
        public MyLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context) {
            this.context = context;
        }




        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {

                StrokeTextView strokeTextView = new StrokeTextView(context,Control.TextSize);
                strokeTextView.Text = e.NewElement.Text;
                strokeTextView.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Purple);
              //  Control.TextSize=50;
                SetNativeControl(strokeTextView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is code about `StrokeTextView`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using static Android.Graphics.Paint;

namespace LabelUpdateDemo.Droid
{
    class StrokeTextView : TextView
    {
        private TextView borderText = null;
        float OriTextSize;
        public StrokeTextView(Context context,float OriTextSize) : base(context)
        {
            borderText = new TextView(context);
            borderText.TextSize = OriTextSize;
            this.TextSize = OriTextSize;
          
            init();
        }
        public StrokeTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {
            borderText = new TextView(context, attrs);
            init();
        }
        public StrokeTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
        {
            borderText = new TextView(context, attrs, defStyle);
            init();
        }



        public void init()
        {
            TextPaint tp1 = borderText.Paint;
            tp1.StrokeWidth = 15;         // sets the stroke width                        
            tp1.SetStyle(Style.Stroke);
            borderText.SetTextColor(Color.Blue);  // set the stroke color
            borderText.Gravity = Gravity;

        }

     
        public override ViewGroup.LayoutParams LayoutParameters { get => base.LayoutParameters; set => base.LayoutParameters = value; }

        protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
        {
            string tt = borderText.Text;


            if (tt == null || !tt.Equals(this.Text))
            {
                borderText.Text = Text;
                this.PostInvalidate();
            }

            base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            borderText.Measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
            borderText.Layout(left, top, right, bottom);
        }

        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            borderText.Draw(canvas);
            base.OnDraw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is code in the xamarin forms.

```
    <Label 
            x:Name = "BTTextStatus"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            Text="Label"
            FontSize="Large"/>
```

If you want to add some custom renderers, you can create a custom label, then add [behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/attached) for this costom label

===============**Update**==================

If you want to add properties, such as `StrokeColor="#0FBEFE"` and `StrokeThickness="3"`

You can create a customLabel control like following code.

```
  public class MyCustomLabel:Label
    {

    
        public static readonly BindableProperty StrokeColorProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached("StrokeColor", typeof(string), typeof(MyCustomLabel), "");
        public string StrokeColor
        {
            get { return base.GetValue(StrokeColorProperty).ToString(); }
            set { base.SetValue(StrokeColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty StrokeThicknessProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached("StrokeThickness", typeof(int), typeof(MyCustomLabel), 0);
        public int StrokeThickness
        {
            get { return (int) base.GetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty); }
            set { base.SetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

Then used it in the `xaml` folder.

```
 <labelupdatedemo:MyCustomLabel 
            x:Name = "BTTextStatus"
            StrokeColor="#0FBEFE"
            StrokeThickness="5"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            TextColor="#0B1751"
            FontSize="Medium"/>
```

In the Android custom renderer like following code.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyCustomLabel), typeof(MyLabelRenderer))]
namespace LabelUpdateDemo.Droid
{
   public class MyLabelRenderer: LabelRenderer
    {
        Context context;
        public MyLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context) {
            this.context = context;
        }




        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            MyCustomLabel  customLabel=(MyCustomLabel) Element;
            var StrokeTextViewColor= customLabel.StrokeColor;

            int StrokeThickness = customLabel.StrokeThickness;
            if (Control != null)
            {

                StrokeTextView strokeTextView = new StrokeTextView(context, Control.TextSize, StrokeTextViewColor,  StrokeThickness);
                strokeTextView.Text = e.NewElement.Text;
                strokeTextView.SetTextColor(Control.TextColors);
            
                SetNativeControl(strokeTextView);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Here is code about `StrokeTextView.cs`

```
    class StrokeTextView : TextView
    {
        private TextView borderText = null;
        float OriTextSize;
        public StrokeTextView(Context context,float OriTextSize,string StrokeTextViewColor, int StrokeThickness) : base(context)
        {
            borderText = new TextView(context);
          
            borderText.TextSize = OriTextSize;
            this.TextSize = OriTextSize;
          
            init(StrokeTextViewColor,  StrokeThickness);
        }
        public void init(string StrokeTextViewColor, int StrokeThickness)
        {
            TextPaint tp1 = borderText.Paint;
            tp1.StrokeWidth = StrokeThickness;         // sets the stroke width                        
            tp1.SetStyle(Style.Stroke);
            borderText.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(StrokeTextViewColor));  // set the stroke color
            borderText.Gravity = Gravity;

        }

     
        public override ViewGroup.LayoutParams LayoutParameters { get => base.LayoutParameters; set => base.LayoutParameters = value; }

        protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
        {
            string tt = borderText.Text;


            if (tt == null || !tt.Equals(this.Text))
            {
                borderText.Text = Text;
                this.PostInvalidate();
            }

            base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            borderText.Measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
            borderText.Layout(left, top, right, bottom);
        }

        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            borderText.Draw(canvas);
            base.OnDraw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

In the IOS, you can use following custom renderer to achieve it.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyCustomLabel), typeof(MyLabelRenderer))]
namespace LabelUpdateDemo.iOS
{
    class MyLabelRenderer: LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            MyCustomLabel myCustomLabel= Element as MyCustomLabel;


            if (Control != null)
            {
                UIStringAttributes strokeTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes();
                // Here is set the StrokeColor
              
                strokeTextAttributes.StrokeColor = Color.FromHex(myCustomLabel.StrokeColor).ToUIColor(); ; 
                //Here is set the StrokeThickness, IOS is diferert from the android, it border is set to the inside the font.
                strokeTextAttributes.StrokeWidth = -1*myCustomLabel.StrokeThickness;

                Control.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(Control.Text, strokeTextAttributes);
                Control.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
            }
        }
    }
   

}
```

Comment: Can you please help me out more? Like giving the full code of Android, IOS and the PCL. Also, the final code where the colors are not hard coded but given to the control from xaml. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have given your solution, try it by yourself, you will learn lots of things.

Comment: @MohamedAshraf Here is my demo. https://github.com/851265601/XFormsAttachProperties

Comment: Even though I found a work around for my issue, but I really respect your effort <3 Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, can you show me how to do the same on IOS ? I will be really happy about that, as I'm using Xamarin Forms as you can see ^^

Comment: @MohamedAshraf I have update the IOS achievement, you can refer to above answer.

Comment: Are there any update for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please accept it(click the `✔` in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me indeed <3
It would be nice if you updated the github as well just in case someone followed it doesn't get lost.

Comment: this is almost perfect, if you changed label property such as label text, the stroke will be gone, hence you need to override OnElementPropertyChanged too, and reapply the stroke